# Is it possible to dynamically output the name of the widgets?

Tags: widgets, theme-options

I am making a theme so I have also made some custom widgets.

I want to know that is it possible to output the widgets names that are built in my theme.

Let me know you that I want to display this info in my theme options page that I have built in the admin area.

**NOTE:** I don`t want to output the widget name that is WordPress inbuilt or plugins ( like woo commerce ) in build. I just want to output the names of widgets that are prebuilt in my theme.

**UPDATE:**

Let Suppose I have made three widgets in my theme with the following name

1. *mi-popular post*
2. *mi-subscribe*
3. *mi-twitter-tweets*

and I have made a new page in admin using add_admin_menu etc function for my theme options.

Now what I want is to echo out only these widget name, id, every information.

**Remember** I want to echo out the widget names which are built in my theme that I have mentioned above. I don't want the names of WordPress inbuilt widget names or any plugins inbuilt widgets names.

Hope You all have understood.

Comment: what does it mean "widget name" please edit the question and clarify it. otherwise, the answer is "yes"

Comment: Do you mean you want to output a particular CSS class or id?

Comment: @MarkKaplun I have updated my question hope you will understand:)